# Dynamically create variables in Jinja2 for loop

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Within a for loop, I'm iterating over a list of dictionaries, and if certain conditions are met, assigning a new variable with the value of a specific dictionary key. If this variable then exists, I want its value assigned to an input field. Example as follows:

```
{% for month in months %}

{% for value in values %}
    {% if value.condition_1 == 'Condition1' %}
        {% if value.condition_2 == 'Condition2' %}

             {% {{ month }}_value_present = value.month_value %}      <<< This line here

        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if {{ month }}_value_present %}     <<< This line here
    <input type="text" name="value_weighting_{{ month }}" class="modal-month-boxes" value="{{ {{ month }}_value_present }}">
{% else %}
    <input type="text" name="value_weighting_{{ month }}" class="modal-month-boxes">
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This approach yields me the following error, which arises from the `{{ month }}` tag:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected

What is the correct way to dynamically create variables in this way?

Comment: consider a different structure such as a dictionary or a list. this isnt even a jinja issue at this point, creating variable "names" dynamically is frowned upon for good reason.

Comment: Indeed, if you could make a dictionary value_present. Then you could assign it like `value_present[month] = value.month_value`.

Answer (score 0):

`{% if {{ month }}_value_present %}` is failing because the parsing is choking. What about trying to use making a string variable, then doing something hacky like using `locals()`, or `getattr` for accessing that value?

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll probably just go with what Paritosh has suggested and append  the values on the Python side. Thanks for the help anyway.